# Add column with values depending on another column to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have got a dataframe to which I want to append a column with values depending on a column in my dataframe.
My dataframe looks somewhat like this:

```
c1  c2  c3
x   2   z
y   5   f
c   3   r
a   11  z
```

Now I want to append another column `c4` based on the values of `c2`.
For all values between 0 and 4 I want to append `"low"`, for values between 5 and 9 I want to append `"medium"` and for those bigger than 10 `"high"`.

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
x   2   z   "low"
y   5   f   "medium"
c   3   r   "low"
a   11  z   "high"
```

Probably the answer is quite simple, but I really can't think of something.

Comment: Look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016723/how-to-add-column-into-a-dataframe-based-on-condition-in-r-programming

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can nest `ifelse` stataments. It's very handy when you are making categorical variables out of continuous ones.

```
data$c4 <- ifelse(data$c2 >= 0 & data$c2 <= 4, 'low',
                  ifelse(data$c2 >=5 & data$c2 <=9, 'medium',
                         ifelse(data$c2 >=10, 'High', 'something else')
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know ifelse() can be nested!

Comment: @Ramona, yes.  very handy when you are making categorical variables out of continuous ones. :)

Comment: It works but with cut() you save yourself a lot of repetition in your code, like the multiple ifelse's and data$c2's. With the 1st argument you refer to your variable, with the 2nd you give the intervals, and with the latter the new categories.

Answer (score 10):

```
df <- read.table(text = "
c1  c2  c3
x   2   z
y   5   f
c   3   r
a   11  z
         ", h = T)

df$c4 <- cut(df$c2, c(-Inf,4,9,Inf), c("low", "medium", "high"))

> df

  c1 c2 c3     c4
1  x  2  z    low
2  y  5  f medium
3  c  3  r    low
4  a 11  z   high
```