# Finding if the values in one column are within the range of several other columns

Tags: r, string, range, comparison, multiple-columns

I am looking for an easy way to find whether the value in a column lies within the range of values in other columns.

My input looks like this:

```
ID  "Q1 Comm - 01 Scope Thesis" "Q1 Comm - 02 Scope Project" "Q1 Comm - 03 Learn Intern"    "Q1 Comm - 04 Biography"    "Q1 Comm - Overall Plan"
10   NA                          NA                           4                              NA      4
31   2                           NA                           NA                             NA      2
225  0                           NA                           NA                             NA      1
243  NA                          2                            NA                             1       0
310  NA                          2                            NA                             1       NA
```

For each unique `ID`, I am interested in identifying when the column `Q1 Comm - Overall Plan` is:

1 - `Below` the `min()` of all the other columns, or

2 - `Above` the `max()` of all the other columns, or

3 - `Within` the range of all the other columns

The complete list of columns (along with the `overall` column) is below:

```
"Q1 Comm - 01 Scope Thesis"
"Q1 Comm - 02 Scope Project"
"Q1 Comm - 03 Learn Intern"
"Q1 Comm - 04 Biography"
"Q1 Comm - 05 Exhibit"
"Q1 Comm - 06 Social Act"
"Q1 Comm - 07 Post Project"
"Q1 Comm - 08 Learn Plant"
"Q1 Comm - 09 Study Narrate"
"Q1 Comm - 10 Learn Participate"
"Q1 Comm - 11 Write 1"
"Q1 Comm - 12 Read 2"
"Q1 Comm - Overall Plan"
```

My required output is something like this:

```
ID  "Q1 Comm - 01 Scope Thesis" "Q1 Comm - 02 Scope Project" "Q1 Comm - 03 Learn Intern"    "Q1 Comm - 04 Biography"    "Q1 Comm - Overall Plan" "Q1_check"
10   NA                          NA                           4                              NA      4 "within"
31   2                           NA                           NA                             NA      2 "within"
225  0                           NA                           NA                             NA      1 "above"
243  NA                          2                            NA                             1       0 "below"
310  NA                          2                            NA                             1       NA NA
```

The dput() for my data frame `df` is below.

```
dput(df)

structure(list(ID = c(10L, 31L, 225L, 243L), Q1.Comm...01.Scope.Thesis = c(NA, 
2L, 0L, NA), Q1.Comm...02.Scope.Project = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L), 
    Q1.Comm...03.Learn.Intern = c(4L, NA, NA, NA), Q1.Comm...04.Biography = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L), Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 
    NA), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), X.2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

##### Note:

I had asked this question here [Finding if a value is within the range of other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898633/finding-if-a-value-is-within-the-range-of-other-columns/67899154#67899154) but the example was too simplified and none of the solutions worked for me.

The question was getting too lengthy, therefore, for the sake of clarity, I am posting this as a new question.

I thank you for your time and help on this post.

Comment: Your posted `dput` does not match your expected result.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated it. It actually contained a list of columns similar to my original data.

Comment: @Sandy, doing it for one Q is rather easy, but for several Qs at once require thinking.  :)  shall I post an answer for this dput?  I am sorry to say that this question is again too simplified for your actual requirement!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

needed_cols <- setdiff(names(df), c("ID", "Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan"))

setDT(df)[, c("min", "max") := transpose(pmap(.SD, range, na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols = needed_cols]
df[, Q1_check := fcase(
    is.na(`Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan`), NA_character_,
    `Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan` < min, "below",
    `Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan` > max, "above",
    default = "within"
  )
]
df[, c("max", "min") := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @det. It seems to work for the given df. A quick question, can it be used inside a for loop, as I have additional variables beginning with name like Q2, then another set of variables beginning with names like Q3. I can, of course run your neat script 3 times or more. But just wondering if it can be updated please?

Comment: Your suggested solution is also working on my original dataset. I just have to repeat it for each of the questions separately. I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: it can be, but I don't know exactly what you want to do inside loop. It might be even possible to do it without loop.

Comment: I've added answer in your other question hope that helps you regarding loop (this question have nothing to do with Q2).

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this with `rowwise` and `c_across`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  summarise(ID = ID,
            Max = `Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan` > max(c_across(-c(ID,`Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan`)),na.rm = TRUE),
            Min = `Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan` < min(c_across(-c(ID,`Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan`)),na.rm = TRUE),
            Range = `Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan` >= range(c_across(-c(ID,`Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan`)),na.rm = TRUE)[1] &
                    `Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan` <= range(c_across(-c(ID,`Q1.Comm...Overall.Plan`)),na.rm = TRUE)[2]) %>%
  mutate(Result = case_when(Max ~ "above",
                            Min ~ "below",
                            Range ~ "within",
                            TRUE ~ NA_character_))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     ID Max   Min   Range Result
  <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr> 
1    10 FALSE FALSE TRUE  within
2    31 FALSE FALSE TRUE  within
3   225 TRUE  FALSE FALSE above 
4   243 NA    NA    NA    NA
```

You can change `summarise` to `mutate` to keep the original columns and/or `select` to get rid of them.

See the [dplyr rowwise tutorial](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-rowwise/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution and for the information on rowwise tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I have revised your dput to suit to your requirements as discussed in the linked question.  I think this will help you.  I used `janitor::clean_names()` which I suggest you to use before proceeding so that your column names are cleaned.

So the revised dput is

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(10L, 31L, 225L, 243L), q1_comm_01_scope_thesis = c(NA, 
2L, 0L, NA), q1_comm_02_scope_project = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L), q1_comm_03_learn_intern = c(4L, 
NA, NA, NA), q1_comm_04_biography = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), q1_comm_overall_plan = c(4L, 
1L, 2L, NA), q2_comm_01_scope_thesis = c(NA, 4, 0, NA), q2_comm_02_scope_project = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 4), q2_comm_03_learn_intern = c(8, NA, NA, NA), q2_comm_04_biography = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 2), q2_comm_overall_plan = c(8, 2, 4, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

df
   id q1_comm_01_scope_thesis q1_comm_02_scope_project q1_comm_03_learn_intern q1_comm_04_biography q1_comm_overall_plan q2_comm_01_scope_thesis
1  10                      NA                       NA                       4                   NA                    4                      NA
2  31                       2                       NA                      NA                   NA                    1                       4
3 225                       0                       NA                      NA                   NA                    2                       0
4 243                      NA                        2                      NA                    1                   NA                      NA
  q2_comm_02_scope_project q2_comm_03_learn_intern q2_comm_04_biography q2_comm_overall_plan
1                       NA                       8                   NA                    8
2                       NA                      NA                   NA                    2
3                       NA                      NA                   NA                    4
4                        4                      NA                    2                   NA
```

Now proceed as suggested. **You have to modify [-5] inside cur_data() to suit to your requirements (as per the relative location of overall_column I think 9 in your case)**

```
library(tidyverse)

split.default(df[-1], gsub('(q\\d*)(.*)', '\\1', names(df[-1]), perl = T)) %>%
  map(., ~ .x %>% bind_cols('id' = df$id) %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(across(ends_with('_overall_plan'), ~ case_when(. < min(cur_data()[-5], na.rm = T) ~ 'below',
                                                              . > max(cur_data()[-5], na.rm = T) ~ 'above',
                                                              is.na(.) ~ NA_character_,
                                                              TRUE ~ 'within'),
                      .names = '{str_remove(.col,"_comm_overall_plan")}_check'))
        ) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = 'id')

# A tibble: 4 x 13
# Groups:   id [4]
  q1_comm_01_scop~ q1_comm_02_scop~ q1_comm_03_lear~ q1_comm_04_biog~ q1_comm_overall~    id q1_check q2_comm_01_scop~ q2_comm_02_scop~ q2_comm_03_lear~ q2_comm_04_biog~
             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>            <int> <int> <chr>               <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1               NA               NA                4               NA                4    10 within                 NA               NA                8               NA
2                2               NA               NA               NA                1    31 below                   4               NA               NA               NA
3                0               NA               NA               NA                2   225 above                   0               NA               NA               NA
4               NA                2               NA                1               NA   243 NA                     NA                4               NA                2
# ... with 2 more variables: q2_comm_overall_plan <dbl>, q2_check <chr>
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the janitor() package. However, the solution is not working on my original dataset.

Comment: That's why I asked you to post a few rows (4 may be) of your complete dataset.  Tell me one more thing, are IDs unique for each row?

Comment: Yes, the IDs are unique. I have pre-processed the data to be in ```wide``` format where all information related to an ID is within their own row.