# How to add column into a dataframe based on condition? (without ifelse)

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I refer to Oscar de Léon's answer to this question: [How to add column into a dataframe based on condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016723/how-to-add-column-into-a-dataframe-based-on-condition)

This is his code:

`iris$Regulation <- c("DOWN", "UP")[ (iris$Sepal.Length >= 5) + 1 ]`

I understand it assigns values to the column "Regulation" and hence creates it, if it's not there yet. But then? I see it works but I don't understand what it is exactly doing. Could you explain what it does?

Comment: The condition returns `FALSE/TRUE`, coded internally as `0/1`. Then add `1` because R vectors are 1-based. The result indexes the vector `c("DOWN", "UP")`. Try doing what @Sotos said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part effectively creates an object with two entries: the potential outcomes `DOWN/UP`. The second is a logical argument indexing one of those outcomes.

Might be easier if we create an object for the outcomes:

```
outcome <- c('DOWN','UP')
```

Square brackets index the object:

```
> outcome[ 2 ]
[1] "UP"
```

Inside the brackets is a logical statement returning `FALSE/TRUE`. Focusing only on the first 5 observations:

```
> iris[1:5,'Sepal.Length'] >= 5
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Which store numerically as `0/1`:

```
> as.numeric(iris[1:5,'Sepal.Length'] >= 5)
[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Addding 1 to the above returns 1s and 2s, which index either `DOWN/UP` in the `outcomes` object:

```
> condition[ (iris[1:5,'Sepal.Length'] >= 5) + 1 ]
[1] "UP"   "DOWN" "DOWN" "DOWN" "UP"
```