# Conditionally calculate column in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I have a table like this:

[image]

I have two teams. I want to award 1 point depending on the KPI:

- for baseball the point is awarded **if** greater or equal than goal.
- for basketball the point is awarded **if** less than goal.

How can I create a Score column that calculates that? Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to check the mutate function from dplyr for exemple, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016723/create-categories-by-comparing-a-numeric-column-with-a-fixed-value) thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create categories by comparing a numeric column with a fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016723/create-categories-by-comparing-a-numeric-column-with-a-fixed-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Teams = c("A", "B"),
  January = c(70, 50),
  KPI = c("Baseball", "Basketball"),
  Goal = c(80, 60)
)

df$Score <- ifelse(df$KPI=="Baseball" & df$January >= df$Goal 
                   | df$KPI=="Basketball" & df$January < df$Goal, 1, 0 )
```

Result:

```
df
  Teams January        KPI Goal Score
1     A      70   Baseball   80     0
2     B      50 Basketball   60     1
```