# Each value greater than x, assign for it a string in a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame with one column `A`, something like this

```
head(df)

    A
1  200
2  230
3  400
4  638
5  502
6  387
```

I want to add a new column. For each value equal or greater than 400 in `A`, there would be nonNormal. otherwise, there would be Normal, something like this

```
    A     B
1  200  Normal
2  230  Normal
3  400  nonNormal
4  638  nonNormal
5  502  nonNormal
6  387  Normal
```

Comment: Use `ifelse` i.e. `df$B <- with(df, ifelse(A >=400, "nonNormal", "Normal"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create categories by comparing a numeric column with a fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016723/create-categories-by-comparing-a-numeric-column-with-a-fixed-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have another option with `case_when`. With this option, you might add more conditions.

```
df %>% mutate(
  B = case_when(
    A >= 400 ~ 'nonNormal',
    A < 400 ~ 'Normal'
  )
)
```

Comment: better (faster, more compressed syntax) to use `if_else` when there is only two outcomes.